# How do I get the following solution (Traveling wave solution of the Burgers equation)?

Tags: calculus

Taken from [Debnath](https://shahfaisal30.weebly.com/uploads/5/9/7/7/59776837/non-linear-partial-differential-equations_for_engneeres_and_scientists.pdf) Chapter 8 page 385, how do I obtain the following?

$$u(\xi)=\frac{u_1+u_2\exp\left(\frac{\xi}{2\nu}(u_1-u_2)\right)}{1+\exp\left(\frac{\xi}{2\nu}(u_1-u_2)\right)}$$

---

**My attempt:**

$\frac{\xi}{2\nu}=-\int{\frac{1}{(u_1-u)(u-u_2)}}du$, where $u_1$ and $u_2$ are constants.

Using: https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=-1%2F%28%28a-x%29%28x-b%29%29
the equation then becomes:

$\frac{\xi}{2\nu}=\frac{\log(u-u_2)-\log(u-u_1)}{u_2-u_1} \tag{1}$

Taking exponentials,

$$\exp\left(\frac{(u_2-u_1)\xi}{2\nu}\right)=\frac{u-u_2}{u-u_1}$$

Rearrange:
$u(\xi)=\frac{u_1\exp\left(\frac{(u_2-u_1)\xi}{2\nu}\right)+u_2}{\exp\left(\frac{(u_2-u_1)\xi}{2\nu}\right)-1}$

which isn't the given solution. So I tried multiplying RHS of equation $(1)$ by $-1$ on both numerator and denominator, which after solving gives:

$u(\xi)=\frac{u_1-u_2\exp\left(\frac{(u_1-u_2)\xi}{2\nu}\right)}{1-\exp\left(\frac{(u_1-u_2)\xi}{2\nu}\right)}$

which again isn't the given form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Assume the result of equation No. 8.3.5 given in the book as***
$$\frac{\xi}{2\nu}= \frac{1}{u_1-u_2}\ln\left(\frac{u_1-u}{u-u_2}\right)$$
***is correct, then*** multiplying both sides by $(u_1 - u_2)$ yields
$$\frac{\xi}{2\nu}(u_1-u_2)= \ln\left(\frac{u_1-u}{u-u_2}\right)$$
, ***then*** it follows (because $e^{\ln(x)}=x$)
$$e^{\frac{\xi}{2\nu}(u_1-u_2)}= \frac{u_1-u}{u-u_2}$$
and ***then*** solving for $u$ we get equation No. 8.3.6
$$\large{u = \frac{u_1 + u_2 e^{\frac{\xi}{2\nu}(u_1-u_2)}}{1 + e^{\frac{\xi}{2\nu}(u_1-u_2)}}}$$

***BUT***
The [wolframalpha calculation of this integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%201%2F((u-u1)*(u-u2))%20du) shows that the result in the book is iffy, because according to this calculation we have

$$\int \frac{1}{(u-u_1)\cdot (u-u_2)} du = -\int \frac{1}{(u_1-u)\cdot (u-u_2)} du = \frac{1}{u_1-u_2}\ln\left(\frac{-(u_1 - u)}{u-u_2}\right)$$

This would give:

$$\large{u = \frac{-u_1 + u_2 e^{\frac{\xi}{2\nu}(u_1-u_2)}}{-1 + e^{\frac{\xi}{2\nu}(u_1-u_2)}}} $$

, which is wrong in this physical context, because according to Fig. 8.1 in the book we have $$u(\xi = 0)=\frac{1}{2}(u_1+u_2)$$ This is only true for the solution from the book! This last (mathematical wolframalpha) solution for $u$ is undefined at $\xi = 0$, because the denominator becomes $0$. The real question here should be, how this integral is tackeled manually (from a physical point of view)...

Comment: The book solution is for $u$ between $u_1$ and $u_2$, but the wolframalpha solution is for $u$ greater than both $u_1$ and $u_2$ [or less than both].